# Boot Camp Windows 10 keeps disconnecting my USB mouse and keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp, usb, bluetooth, mouse

I recently downloaded Windows 10 on my 2016 MacBook Pro 13 inch using Boot Camp. My RK61 Bluetooth mechanical keyboard and my usb mouse works fine when I'm operating on macOS. But when I switch to Windows 10, my mouse and keyboard says that it's connected, but my mouse will disconnect randomly and become unresponsive.

I have a 3.0 USB Type C Hub: [https://www.amazon.com/Hiearcool-MacBook-Multiport-Compatible-Nintendo/dp/B07WPTG7NX/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WPTG7NX)

I'm not sure why this keeps happening. I know that that my mouse isn't defective, since I've connected it to another laptop and it works perfectly fine without any glitches. I've also gone into my device manager on Windows 10 to turn off power saving options for USB. I also tried uninstalling the device as well as updating the driver.